# How to secure React Routes Using React v18 and React Router Dom v6.11

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

**App.js**

```
import { useKeycloak } from "@react-keycloak/web"

  const { initialized } = useKeycloak()
  if (!initialized) {
    return <h3>Loading ... !!!</h3>
  }
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
          <Route path="/secure" element={<TestCompoent />} /> //How to secure this component
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
}
```

**TestComponent.tsx**

```
function TestCompoent() {
  return <div>Private</div>
}

export default TestCompoent
```

How to create a component `PrivateRoute`, that checks is user is logged in, otherwise navigate to keycloak login

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't completely secure something on the web interface, but you can restrict access to a private link! For example:
You can create Wrapper for private links:

```
<Route element={<RequireAuthRoute />}>
 <Route path="trainer" element={<TrainerComponent />} />
 <Route path="admin" element={<AdminComponent />} />
</Route>
```

and wrapper. In this wrapper you can check, is user valid, AUTHENTICATED or another checking:

```
import { useLocation, Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { authStatusSelector } from "../redux/features/auth/auth.slice";
import { FETCH_STATUS } from "../redux/types";

const RequireAuthRoute = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const status = useSelector(authStatusSelector);

  if (status !== FETCH_STATUS.AUTHENTICATED) {
    return <Navigate to="/main" state={{ from: location }} />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
}

export default RequireAuthRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function TestCompoent({children}) {

if (isLogged) {
  return children;
} else {
  return <h3>Loading ... !!!</h3>
}

export default TestCompoent;
```

**App.js**

```
return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
          <Route path="/secure" element={<TestCompoent>your component here</TestCompoent>} /> //How to secure this component
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  )
```

**Explaination:**
Here `TestComponent` is PrivateRoute inside it checks if user is logged or not. You can replace `isLogged` veriable with your condition which checks the user logining. if user is not logged in it will return `Loading...` (where you can return you component where you want to navigate user when user is not logged in.)

if user is alredy logged in then if will return `children` which is component.

In `App.js` as you can see:

```
<TestCompoent>your component here</TestCompoent>
```

`your component here you can put your secure component` which is wrapped by `TestComponent` [every thing you wrap with `TestComponent` will be display as `children` in TestCompoment].

you just need to wrap your secure component with `TestComponent` wrapper :)
if you still don't understand feel free to ping me on discord [discord link is in my bio].

Hope you got your answer. if you see any mistake or have any suggestions feel free to comment here.